# submit function of jquery submit form and not validate the livevalidation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have used the livevalidation.js for validating the form field. But I can't validate radio button with live validation for that I have written following code on form submit jquery event.

The problem is that, when I select these radio buttons and not other fields of form, then it submit the form and model validation applied, but it should applied live-validation.

what is the problem in my code or submit function?

```
$('#new_league_info').submit(function(){
            if($('#league_info_state').val() != '')
            {
                if($('.re_conditioner_radio').is(':checked')){
                    $('#reconditioner_msg').css("hidden");
                    var spans = $('.reconditioner_err');
                    spans.text('');
                }

                else{
                    $('#reconditioner_msg').replaceWith('<span class=" reconditioner_err LV_invalid">Please Select a Reconditioner</span>');
                    return false;

                }
            }

            if ($(".view_offer_checkbox").is(':checked')){
                $('#manufacturer_msg').css("hidden");
                var spans = $('.manufacturer_err');
                spans.text('');
            }
            else{
                $('#manufacturer_msg').replaceWith('<span class=" manufacturer_err LV_invalid">Please Select a Manufacturer</span>');
                return false;

            }
        });
```

Comment: Uhm, do you mean by live validation "clicking on the submit button and bevor sending it to your controller check it" or do you mean "when a radio button is clicked do some AJAX or other magic and check if it was ok to click this?"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

to prevent the default behaviour when the submit-button is clicked and to do your own validation:

```
$('#new_league_info').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: actually this not submitted my form but , it doesn't show any error, it means live validation not applied on the other fields.